# Flex TabNavigator Tab Color Not Working

Tags: css, apache-flex, tabnavigator

I am trying to set the tabs in a TabNavigator to orange. I have tried a number of different ways, but none of them seem to work (i.e. the background is always standard grey).

```
<fx:Style>
@namespace mx "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx";
mx|TabNavigator {
   fillColors: #FBE0CC;
}
</fx:Style>
```

Also...

```
<fx:Style>
@namespace mx "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx";
mx|Tab {
   fillColors: #FBE0CC;
}
</fx:Style>
```

Also...

```
.myTabStyle {
    tabStyleName: "myTabs"
}
.myTabs {
    backgroundColor: #ff0000;
    fillColor: #FBE0CC;
}
```

With

```
<mx:TabNavigator ... styleName="myTabStyle" .. >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this one?

```
mx|Tab {
    fillColors: #FBE0CC, #FBE0CC;
    fillAlphas: 1, 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. It seems I not only needed to use the code you provided, but also add the Halo theme as noted in this blog post [link](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2009/07/14/using-the-halo-theme-in-flex-4/)